# How can I access these json object in python

Tags: python, json

I'm making some data visualization from movies database api and I already access the data in the normal way but when i load the json data and for loop to print it, the data that out is just the column but I need to access the object inside.

```
url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key="+ api_key 
+"&language=en- US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=
false&include_video=false&page=1" # api url

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
raw_json = response.read().decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(raw_json)

for j in data:
    print(j)
```

i expect the output would be

```
[{'popularity': 15,
  'id': 611,
  'video': False,
  'vote_count': 1403,
  'vote_average': 8.9,
  'title': 'lalalalo'},{....}]
```

but the actual output is

```
page
total_results
total_pages
results
```

Comment: Can you show the output for `print(j)`?

Comment: It seems that you are iterating on the keys of a mapping. Check what ``j`` is instead of trying to print is elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: if it is dictionary then loop normally gives only keys. You would have to use `data.items()` in `for..in...` to get pairs `(key, value)` . But first you should check `print(data)` and `print(type(data))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are one level down. You are looping through the metadata.

Try changing your code to

```
import json
import urllib.request
api_key = "your api code"

url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=" + api_key +"&language=en- US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1" # api url

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
raw_json = response.read().decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(raw_json)

for j in data['results']:
    print(j)
```

You need to change

```
data
```

to

```
data['results']
```

Comment: Thank you it my false that i just miss this spot thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use requests module...

```py
import requests
import json

your_link = " "
r = requests.get(your_link)
data = json.loads(r.content)
```

You shall have the json loaded up, then use your key "results" ["results"] and loop through the data you got.